# How can I enlarge video fullscreen without the affected interface project in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, fullscreen, flvplayback

I have a problem I do not know how to correct it.

I want to work a full-screen in my project.  But the video of the entire screen, and I want to show the entire video of the screen appears when you click the button on the control panel only video of a button.

Do not know the solution to the problem I want to help me.  I USE this code in AS3:

```js
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

Example:

Illustrative image:

[image: screen-capture]

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not clear ! What's the problem ? What do you want exactly ?

Comment: Is there someone who knows the solution to the problem???

Comment: I put an example, take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do what you want using the full-screen button of the `FLVPlayback` component because it's related to the full-screen mode of the stage. Instead, you can use another button in your stage to activate the full-screen mode of your video player.

Take this example where I used two buttons, 1st button to full-screen the whole animation and the 2nd one to full-screen the video when the animation is on full-screen display mode :

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.addEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN, function(e:FullScreenEvent){
    // disable the full-screen mode of the FLVPlayback component everytime the stage leaves the full-screen mode
    if(!e.fullScreen){
        player.fullScreenTakeOver = false;
    }
})

// player is my FLVPlayback component

// activate video smoothing (option)
player.getVideoPlayer(0).smoothing = true;

// disable the full-screen mode of the FLVPlayback component
player.fullScreenTakeOver = false;

// this button is to activate the full-screen mode of the FLVPlayback component
btn_player_fullscreen.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent){
    // if our stage is on fullscreen mode
    if(stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN){
        // activate the full-screen mode of the FLVPlayback component
        player.fullScreenTakeOver = true;
    }
})

// this button is to activate the full-screen mode of the stage
btn_fullscreen.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent){
    if(stage.displayState != StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN){
        stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
    }
})
```

You can see this code working [here](http://www.fastswf.com/AJ39q90) ( I didn't use a skin for my video player ).

Of course, this is just an example to show you a manner to do what you are looking for, you have to improve and adapt it to your specific needs.

Hope that can help.

Comment: Hello akmozo
This does not work
I do not want to add a button I meant to exist in the control panel video button .. It does not work if full screen
With the following code player.fullScreenTakeOver = false;

Comment: @nadia Hi, I told you in the 1st line of my answer that you can not use the fullscreen button of the FLVPlayback component, that's why you have to use another button to do what you want.

Comment: I want to be full screen in the project
The video normal size
And when you press the zoom button on the control panel video is full screen As in the example attached

Comment: ok ,I understand you
I'll try it.
You all the thanks and appreciation to help me.

Comment: @nadia I understand what you mean and what you want, but you can not do that without another button.

Comment: See File. Example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9BcYjTM8tPoMmY0aTRhMmtLMDQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @nadia OK, and what's the problem ?

Comment: @nadia I edited your code, and It's working fine, you can download it from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/i6ciarz2y0n7zek/stack29138040.zip) ( I put just the FLA, SWF and HTML page ) you have to test it in the same dir as your original project.

Comment: Thank you
But do not benefit me
Because I want to work full-screen at the beginning of open
And not by pressing a button..

Comment: May be needed to design the control panel for the video of no use components.

Comment: @nadia You can not pass to fullscreen mode without user's interaction ( mouse click or keypress ), take a look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS2E9C7F3B-6A7C-4c5d-8ADD-5B23446FBEEB.html).

Comment: >>I want to help programming button on the computer to download video?

Answer (score 0):

Add `<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />`  in your html embed code(2 times).

Also remove this code `stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;`

It will work after you click mouse only.

If you want fullscreen on other button use:

```
fullScreenButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fullScreenListener);
function fullScreenListener(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if(stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.NORMAL)
        stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
    else
        stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
}
```

More info [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/full_screen_mode.html).

To off FLVPlaybackComponent fullScreenTakeOver use

```
myVideoPlayer.fullScreenTakeOver = false;
```

Comment: in your case Flv component intercepts fullscreen event. So you see black color. Try to select video and click fullscreen. You'll see fullscreen video.

Comment: to off this use `myVideoPlayer.fullScreenTakeOver = false;`

Comment: i don't understand what do you want:) If you want only video at fullscreen use `myVideoPlayer.fullScreenTakeOver = true;` If you want all swf in fullscreen use `myVideoPlayer.fullScreenTakeOver = false;` and change components sizes and positions on stage RESIZE event.

Comment: I tried that coed  myVideoPlayer.fullScreenTakeOver = false; But fullscreen video button does not work then.

Comment: what do you mean "video button does not work "? I try your example: if click this button I get http://joxi.ru/LmGVk0jfKQYMrl if click yet window returns to original size and position.

Comment: may be this code will help you `import fl.video.FLVPlayback;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.events.Event;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE; 
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
myVideoPlayer.source = "videos/";
myVideoPlayer.fullScreenTakeOver = false;
function loadMyVideo(url:String):void {
 myVideoPlayer.source = url;
}
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onResizeListener);
function onResizeListener(e:Event) {
 myVideoPlayer.width = stage.stageWidth - myVideoPlayer.x;
 myVideoPlayer.height = stage.stageHeight - myVideoPlayer.y - 50;
}`

Comment: Yup
Do you know a solution to it

Answer (score 0):

Disable scaling

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

Turn off `fullScreenTakeOver`

```
flv_playback.fullScreenTakeOver = false;
```

and enter to the full screen mode

```
flv_playback.enterFullScreenDisplayState();
```

Comment: >>I want to help programming button on the computer to download video?