# How to Make a swf file without a title bar and bar control IN AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

As in the following image .
How do I delete a file title bar and the menu bar of the file swf in AS3?
Without making the Full-screen for the swf file ?

[image: 11]

Comment: You can't do that in FlashPlayer but you can in Adobe AIR.

Comment: @subdan Can you answer this question؟  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138040/how-can-i-enlarge-video-fullscreen-without-the-affected-interface-project-in-as3/29198192?noredirect=1#comment46847492_29198192)

Comment: Yes. I'll answer within half an hour.

Comment: I don't understand where is your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWFs do not have title bars or menus in them. What you are looking at is the window of the [Standalone Flash Player](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#playerType), running a SWF. AFAIK the Standalone Flash Player does not have any feature to hide its window chrome (other than fullscreen).

You can use AIR (desktop application) with `systemChrome=none`: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e09.html

Comment: thanks Aaron ,Can you help me out here
  Since you have experience .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138040/how-can-i-enlarge-video-fullscreen-without-the-affected-interface-project-in-as3/29198192?noredirect=1#comment46847492_29198192

Comment: I beg you..Can you explain to me programming..
I use Adobe Flash Professional CS6 : AS3

Comment: All of programming?? :) What are you trying to do?

Comment: Delete the title bar and the menu bar of the Flash Player file.

Comment: Ok well like I said (and @subdan) you can't do this with the Flash Player, but you can with an AIR app. Are you able to use an AIR app?